# How to solve Hibernate "ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry " Exception

Tags: mysql, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, sqlexception

It's been 2 days now that I test to solve this problem but nothing works.
I have these entities implyed in a bidirectional relation.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "T_user" )
public class T_user implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
   private Long               id_user;

   @OneToOne( targetEntity = T_infosProfile.class, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true )
   private T_infosProfile     infosProfile;

   public void setInfosProfile( T_infosProfile infosProfile ) {
    this.infosProfile = infosProfile;
   }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "T_infosProfile" )
public class T_infosProfile {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
   private Long       id_infos;

   @OneToOne( targetEntity = T_user.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
   @JoinColumn( name = "id_user", unique = true, nullable = false )
   private T_user user;

     @Column( name = "pourcentage_completion", length = 3, updatable = true, unique = false )
     private Integer    pourcentageCompletion;

     @Column( name = "infos_identite", nullable = false, updatable = true, length = 1, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)" )
     private Boolean    infosIdentiteCompleted;

     @Column( name = "infos_coordonnees", nullable = false, updatable = true, length = 1, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)" )
     private Boolean    infosCoordonneesCompleted;

     @Column( name = "infos_bancaires", nullable = false, updatable = true, length = 1, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)" )
     private Boolean    infosBancaireCompleted;

     @Column( name = "infos_chicowa", nullable = false, updatable = true, length = 1, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)" )
     private Boolean    infosCompleted;

   //the setter method
   public void setUser( T_user user) {
      this.user = user;
      this.infosIdentiteCompleted = true;
      this.pourcentageCompletion = 0;
      this.infosCoordonneesCompleted = this.user.getInfosCoordonnees() == null ? false : true;
      this.infosBancaireCompleted = this.user.getInfosBancaire() == null ? false : true;
      this.infosCompleted = this.user.getInfosCompleted() == null ? false : true;

      if ( this.infosCoordonneesCompleted == true ) {
        this.pourcentageCompletion = 50;
    }
      if ( this.infosBancaireCompleted == true && this.pourcentageCompletion == 50 ) {
        this.pourcentageCompletion = 75;
    }
      if ( this.infosChicowaCompleted == true && this.pourcentageCompletion == 75 ) {
        this.pourcentageCompletion = 100;
    }
  }
}
```

I also have this method which is used to update the user's infosProfile :

```
@Service
public class UIServiceImpl implements UIService {

  @Autowired
  private TinfosProfileRepository   infosProfileRepository;

  @Override
  public T_infosProfile saveInfosPorfile( T_user connectedUser ){
    T_infosProfile infosProfile = connectedUser.getInfosProfile();
    infosProfile.setUser( connectedUser );
    connectedUser.setInfosProfile( infosProfile );
    try {
        return infosProfileRepository.save( infosProfile );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw new ExceptionsDAO( e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

But when I call this method it works for a one situation but for another one I got this exception :

```
10-04-2017 16:27:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
10-04-2017 16:27:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry '8' for key 'UK_bkariaocmnn2rlh477hvoqkyf'
```

I just want to update infosProfile's attributes of the current user.
The situation where it works fine it's when only one infosProfile's attribute is updated but when I update 2 attributes at the same time and try to saveInfosProfile(), the exception is raised.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after losting 4 days I found a solution which seems working. Here my solution :

```
@Override
public T_infosProfile saveInfosPorfile( T_user connectedUser ){
  T_infosProfile infosProfile = infosProfileRepository.findByUser(connectedUser); // I had to load by the user before saving it.
  infosProfile.setUser( connectedUser );
  connectedUser.setInfosProfile( infosProfile );
  try {
    return infosProfileRepository.save( infosProfile );
  } catch ( Exception e ) {
    throw new ExceptionsDAO( e.getMessage() );
  }
}
```

For me it a strange behavior as the user is the same as whom is saved in the table. Thanks Hibernate !

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message and it's self explanatory as it's saying value `8` is already existing in that column. It's throwing that error since you have defined a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on that particular column

```
Duplicate entry '8' for key 'UK_bkariaocmnn2rlh477hvoqkyf'
```

Additional: look at your constraint name `UK_bkariaocmnn2rlh477hvoqkyf`. That's what happens when you don't name your constraint while creating it.

Comment: I know but as you can see I just save the existing entity I do not create a new instance so I don't know why this exception is raised.

Comment: What do you mean by : " That's what happens when you don't name your constraint while creating it."

Comment: @akuma8, you get a unreadable constraint name which is system generated.

Comment: How can I change it ? I've never defined this constraint  myself

Answer (score 0):

Having battled this problem in my spring project for a while, i was able to use the below code solve the issue i was facing.

```
  infosProfile=null;

  try {

      infosProfile = infosProfileRepository.save( infosProfile );
  } 
  catch (PersistenceException ex) {

        Throwable cause1 = ex.getCause();

        if(!isNull(cause1)){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(cause1.getCause().getMessage());

        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(ex.getMessage());
    }
```